# How to get aac audio from mp4 container? (Windows Phone 7 & C#)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, stream, mp4, aac

I write windows phone 7 application and there is a next problem:

My app gets a stream of file with audio in aac format which is in mp4 container. So I need get from this stream sequence of bytes with only aac data. How can I do that?

After that I need to use this data in MediaStreamSource class. Therefore it is also necessary to obtain information such as bitrate of aac frames. Will be that information in the resulting sequence of bytes, or it can also be obtained from the mp4 container?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is the link from where you can get the header of the ACC Frame.
http://wiki.multimedia.cx/index.php?title=ADTS
Read first 9 bytes and from that read bits accordingly to get the value.
i.e. bit from 30 to 43 gives the total length of the frame.

hope this will help you to start.